# how to set OnClickListener to the parts of this image

Tags: android, jquery-animate, onclicklistener

i want to set OnClickListeners to the parts of this image because i want to do this animation.

[image]

When the app stars, the part A of the image is animated, is scaleted(only the part A), if i do a click over B,C or D, the image rotate bringing the letter selected to the place where is A in the first time and scaleted the part selected, and the behavior is the same with the other letters.

How can i do that, i have to cut for parts the image or i can work with the current image. I really dont know how to do it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: link of the image http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-y3RJtuieSxo/VNTQIAMNrfI/AAAAAAAAA8w/Lyl_p9IjSQE/s1600/anim3.jpg

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach would be to place empty views on top of the image.  You can then set the onClickListener for each of those views to do what you want to do.

A second approach would be to override onTouch(MotionEvent e) and determine if the motion event was in the correct area and animate as needed.

Comment: First, thanks for response, i did the first option yoy said but rather than rotate the image when i click over A,B,C or D i uses two buttons "Next" and "Back" and do the animation i want, but now i want to make it work when the letters is clicked, i would try with the second option, i have to invest how to determine the area of A,B,C,D using el OnTouchListener